# How to change my method to generic methods?What's wrong with my codes?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, c#-3.0

I have 3 classes called `Student,Worker,People` which may come from different project.All of them have the two same property: `name,age`.Now when I want to change `People` to `Student`,I have to write a method called `ChangePeopleToStudent`, when I want to change `People` to `Worker`,I have to write a method called `ChangePeopleToWorker`.I try to use generic methods to write only one method,but it seems wrong.How to fix it?

**Three classed**

```
public class  Student
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public int Age { get; set; }
           public int MathPoint { get; set; } 
       }
       public class Worker
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public int Age { get; set; }
           public string WorkPlace { get; set; }
       }
       public class People
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public int Age { get; set; }
           public string Country { get; set; }
       }
```

**My two change method**

```
 public static Student ChangePeopleToStudent(People people)
       {
           return new Student
           {
               Name = people.Name,
               Age = people.Age
           };
       }
       public static Worker ChangePeopleToWorker(People people)
       {
           return new Worker
           {
               Name = people.Name,
               Age = people.Age
           };
       }
```

**Generic methods：How to fix it?**

```
public static T ChangePeopleToWorker<T>(People people)
           where T : Student, Worker,new T()
       {
           return new T
           {
               Name = people.Name,
               Age = people.Age
           };
       }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't say `where T: SomeClass, SomeUnrelatedClass` and have it work.  You'd never fulfill both conditions.

Comment: You need to create a common base class or interface, (that contains name and age) and have your various classes inherit from it.  Then use that base class for you generic method `where T : SomeBaseClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an interface (or a base class - I'm assuming an interface in my example) e.g.:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

It should be implemented by all your classes. Then you'll be able to write:

```
public static T ChangePersonTo<T>(IPerson person)
where T : IPerson, new T()
{
   return new T
   {
       Name = person.Name,
       Age = person.Age
   };
}
```

Comment: Person class is a json from other project called project A and has not interface,I can only serialize it in project B.May be I should create an interface.

Answer (score 2):

.NET does not support multiple inheritance, so `where T : Student, Worker` is not a plausible condition.  If you want T to be *either* `Student` or `Worker` you'll need to define a common base class (or interface), or define two different methods.

If `People` should be the common class between the two you can simplify your classes:

```
   public class  Student : People
   {
       public int MathPoint { get; set; } 
   }
   public class Worker : People
   {
       public string WorkPlace { get; set; }
   }
   public class People
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: People is from the other project and pass it by json string.If I use your codes,It seems wrong because the Student and worker do not have the property called 'Country'

Comment: @Lyly It was just an example - it may not fit your case.  The point is you need a base class or interface.